# Symfony2 check the value of form row

Tags: forms, symfony

I need to add to table Workers some data. Main idea is that Every Worker have his own Identify pass. Which every worker set by his own. They are all strings.

Structure from table:

> NAME
>
> SURNAME
>
> PHONENUMBER
>
> **IDENTPASS**

My problem is:

I need to :

1. Check if value of **IDENTPASS** is **UNIQE**

But everytime I what to EDIT this form, but change different row(eg. NAME) in form  I get an error because he says that the value of IDENTPASS exist. Because he want to save it again and there is already this value...

Now i got MANY IF`s which is I thing bad IDEA. And not all works.

**MY CONTROLLER:**

```
public function AcmeAction() {
    if (!is_null($id)){
        $employee=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainCoreBundle:Employee')->find($id);
        $passFromBase = $employee->getIdentpass();
        $employeeForm = $this->createForm(new EmployeeType(), $employee);
        if ($request->getMethod() == "POST") {
            $employeeForm->bind($request);
            if ($employeeForm->isValid()) {
                //1. IF value of ROW is thesame for CURRENT USER ->SAVE()
                $pracownik =$employeeRepo->find($id);
                if(( $pracownik->getIdentpass()==$employeeForm->get('identpass')->getData())){

                    $employee->setIdentpass($employeeForm->get('identpass')->getData());
                    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($employee);
                    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('employee_index'));
                }
                //IF VALUE OF ROW FROM FORM EXIST IN DATA BASE 
                // IF YES (so bad) redirect back to form
                elseif($employeeRepo->findOneByIdentpass($employeeForm->get('identpass')->getData())==true){
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('employee_edit', array('id' => $id)));
                }
                // IF NO(so value is new) THEN SAVE TO BASE
                else{
                    $employee->setIdentpass($employeeForm->get('identpass')->getData());
                    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($employee);
                    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
                    return $this->render('MainAdminBundle:Employee:entity.html.twig', $this->getViewConstants(array('form' => $employeeForm->createView())));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //IF NEW EMPLOYEE
    else{
        $employeeForm = $this->createForm(new EmployeeType(), $employee);
        if ($request->getMethod() == "POST") {
            $employeeForm->bind($request);
            if ($employeeForm->isValid()) {
                //IF IDENTPASS EXIST IN BASE redirect back to form
                if($employeeRepo->findOneByIdentpass($employeeForm->get('identpass')->getData())==true){
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('employee_edit', array('id' => $id)));

                }
                else{//IF VALUE of Identpass DONT EXIST IN BASE SAVE()
                    $employee->setIdentpass($employeeForm->get('identpass')->getData());
                    $employee->setSpot($spot);
                    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($employee);
                    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('employee_index'));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('MainBundle:Employee:entity.html.twig', $this->getViewConstants(array('form' => $employeeForm->createView(), 'pass'=>$passFromBase)));
}
```

Comment: Ok, there are few things you could improve here... writing the answer now...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know if I covered it all but I think this can get started. Please observe the we are using the same form  for insert nad update. This is by no means fully completed code that you could plug and play but rather scratching the surface of what you could do.

```
public function insertEditAction($id){
    $employeeRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainCoreBundle:Employee');

    if (!is_null($id)){
        $employee=$employeeRepo->find($id); // For update
    }else{
        $employee = new Employee(); // For insert
    }

    $employeeForm = $this->createForm(new EmployeeType(), $employee);

    if ( $request->getMethod() === "POST"){
        $form->bind($request);

        if ( $form->isValid()){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $existingByIdentPass = $employeeRepo->findOneByIdentpass($employee->getIdentpass());

            // If there is some other employee with this IDENT_PASS then redirect back to form
            if($existingByIdentPass !== NULL && $existingByIdentPass->getId() !== $employee->getId()){
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('employee_edit', array('id' => $id)));
            }

            // New employee, set the SPOT and PERSIST
            // calling persist is only required when creating new record
            if ( $employee->getId() === NULL ){
                $employee->setSpot($spot);
                $em->persist($employee);
            }

            // Flush the changes
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('employee_index'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('MainBundle:Employee:entity.html.twig', $this->getViewConstants(array('form' => $employeeForm->createView(), 'pass'=>$passFromBase)));
}
```